# Prevent the installation of a specific kernel version

Tags: apt, package-management

Having had major problems with kernel 3.11.0-14 (WLAN, desktop login, ALSA crashes) I decided to back out -14, returning to 3.11.0-12.

**>>ALL<<  problems then  disapeared.**

Now I want to block 3.11.0-14 from automatically reinstalling but I am prepared to accept higher versions than -14 in future packages updates.

Anyone have ideas on how to block -14 from reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Just put that package on hold, that should prevent the installation of the package but no the upgrade of `linux-generic`:

```
echo "linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

You can also modify the GRUB configuration to use other entries instead of -14 kernel. Please, also consider reporting a bug against the kernel to fix those issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had already dumped 3.11.0-14 by a synaptics deinstall which seemed to me to be the cleanest  way to back out, followed by sudo extlinux-update, so GRUB is already in sync. This may be the reason that the terminal froze when doing echo "linux-image-3.11.0-14-generic hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections as you suggested (because it was gone already). BTW - where is/would be this kernel "blacklisted"? In /etc/dkpg files, I couldn't find anywhere with this blacklist function.